# Is it possible to snap a vertex of a shape to a specific point of a nurb curve?

Tags: 3d, maya, snapping

I almost get the feeling that no matter what I try to use curves for, it's not their intended use, so I can't do the thing.

Onto the question.

**How do I snap 1 to 2?**
[image]

Snapping to curves doesn't snap to the exact point on the curve, and snapping to points doesn't seem to notice them.

Comment: Operation of 3D apps is not really in scope here. Its not graphic design, just how to use software. Anyway select mesh, enable transtate tool, hold d and middleclick the vertex you wish to snap release d. hold c middleclick on curve and drag so your at the edge. You can also snap to curve points if you turn them visible hen not in component mode. Yes in maya you need middle mouse button.

Comment: @joojaa Thank you for the warning, and thank you for making me notice I would need to edit the question (assuming I'd have it stay and not get migrated). One problem though: I want it to snap to a specific point; Not just the end of the curve.  I want to snap other vertices on the rounder side of the quarter-cylinder to one of the 7 **points**; Not just the two end-points.

Comment: You can snap to points just make them visible first. thete is really no place to migrate untill 3D graphics hits beta

Comment: @joojaa If you could tell me how to make them perma-visible, you would save my day.

Comment: @joojaa Okay, it works, but having to select Multi, then the vertex of one object, then the point of the curve is incredibly wonky. Making the edit points perma-visible would solve an issue I've struggled with for several days.

Comment: there is a option for that in edit menu i think, but dont remember use the search menu function in the help dialog. Havent seriously  used maya in months, (except i did use it today to calculate the center of hravity of a surface, but then i had to write a plugin). I can look it up later.

Comment: @joojaa If I figure it out myself, I'll try to squeeze in an answer before this question gets closed. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Display -> NURBS -> CV or EP and yes that works even for béziers

Comment: 3D Questions are a weird fit on our website. They aren't off-topic, but we have very little 3D expertise around here. There is a proposal for a 3D StackExchange site that could use your support: [3D Computer Graphics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/86368/3d-computer-graphics)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, select the curve whose points you would want to snap a vertex to. Go to **Display -> NURBs -> CV**; This will make the points visible on only the selected curve(s).

After that, simply select the vertex of the mesh and snap to whichever point on the curve that is now displaying just as you would with any other point (by holding V (Snap to points); Works for single axis snapping as well).